# Is there any official place to find OpenCV article references?

Tags: opencv

I'am having a hard time trying to find the article which is referenced in the cvFindContours 
algorithm, it is  "Topological structural analysis of digitized binary images by border following" Satoshi Suzuki and Keiichi Abe. [suzuki85]

So I wonder if there any resource where all the OpenCV references are stashed.

Also, any explanations on how the cvFindContours algorithm works would be also useful.Thanks!

Comment: I remember trying to find that very same paper. I ended up paying for it.

Answer (score 8):

Found it http://tpf-robotica.googlecode.com/svn-history/r397/trunk/Vision/papers/SA-CVGIP.PDF

Previous link no longer works

New link> https://www.dropbox.com/s/v5n49xraff8o4y7/SA-CVGIP.PDF?dl=0